# unhcheck the legend on button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have created a chart with chart.js and I have onclick event for the legend .I want to shown all the legend without strikeout

```js
 const totalizer = {
    id: 'totalizer',
    beforeUpdate: chart => {
        let totals = {}
        let utmost = 0

            chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset, datasetIndex) => {
                if (chart.isDatasetVisible(datasetIndex)) {
                    utmost = datasetIndex
                        dataset.data.forEach((value, index) => {
                            totals[index] = (totals[index] || 0) + value
                        })
                }
            })
            chart.$totalizer = {
            totals: totals,
            utmost: utmost
        }
    }
}

new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Brut', 'Net imposable', 'Net'],
    datasets: [{"data":[10,20,10],"label":"1st Presentation \/ Meeting","backgroundColor":"#7B68EE"},{"data":[109,82,22],"label":"Hold\/Uncategorized","backgroundColor":"#B0C4DE"},{"data":[4,14,1],"label":"SGL","backgroundColor":"#F4A460"},{"data":[1,0,0],"label":"PGL","backgroundColor":"#BC8F8F"},{"data":[1,8,1],"label":"QO under evaluation","backgroundColor":"#2E8B57"},{"data":[38,37,16],"label":"Follow-On Meetings","backgroundColor":"#6495ED"},{"data":[9,6,0],"label":"MGL","backgroundColor":"#FFA500"},{"data":[6,32,0],"label":"Identified Opportunities","backgroundColor":"#6B8E23"},{"data":[0,2,0],"label":"RGL","backgroundColor":"#DEB887"}],"yearly":[{"data":[2],"label":"RGL","backgroundColor":"#DEB887"},{"data":[40],"label":"1st Presentation \/ Meeting","backgroundColor":"#7B68EE"},{"data":[10],"label":"QO under evaluation","backgroundColor":"#2E8B57"},{"data":[1],"label":"PGL","backgroundColor":"#BC8F8F"},{"data":[38],"label":"Identified Opportunities","backgroundColor":"#6B8E23"},{"data":[19],"label":"SGL","backgroundColor":"#F4A460"},{"data":[213],"label":"Hold\/Uncategorized","backgroundColor":"#B0C4DE"},{"data":[15],"label":"MGL","backgroundColor":"#FFA500"},{"data":[91],"label":"Follow-On Meetings","backgroundColor":"#6495ED"}],"user":[{"data":[0,1,0,0,2,14,7,0,1,2,0,2,1,4,0,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"Identified Opportunities","backgroundColor":"#6B8E23"},{"data":[5,2,0,9,3,0,2,6,5,0,3,0,0,0,2,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"1st Presentation \/ Meeting","backgroundColor":"#7B68EE"},{"data":[149,2,39,0,11,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"Hold\/Uncategorized","backgroundColor":"#B0C4DE"},{"data":[0,2,0,2,0,0,6,4,1,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"SGL","backgroundColor":"#F4A460"},{"data":[2,1,0,0,4,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"QO under evaluation","backgroundColor":"#2E8B57"},{"data":[7,42,0,21,8,0,5,1,0,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"Follow-On Meetings","backgroundColor":"#6495ED"},{"data":[0,3,0,6,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"MGL","backgroundColor":"#FFA500"},{"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"PGL","backgroundColor":"#BC8F8F"},{"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"RGL","backgroundColor":"#DEB887"}]},"filter":{"weekly":["Week 1","Week 2","Week 3","Week 4"]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true
       
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    },
    legend: {
       onClick: function(e, legendItem) {
          var index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
          var ci = this.chart;
          var alreadyHidden = (ci.getDatasetMeta(index).hidden === null) ? false : ci.getDatasetMeta(index).hidden;       
          var anyOthersAlreadyHidden = false;
          var allOthersHidden = true;

          // figure out the current state of the labels
          ci.data.datasets.forEach(function(e, i) {
            var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(i);
            
            if (i !== index) {
              if (meta.hidden) {
                anyOthersAlreadyHidden = true;
              } else {
                allOthersHidden = false;
              }
            }
          });
          
          // if the label we clicked is already hidden 
          // then we now want to unhide (with any others already unhidden)
          if (alreadyHidden) {
            ci.getDatasetMeta(index).hidden = null;
          } else { 
            // otherwise, lets figure out how to toggle visibility based upon the current state
            ci.data.datasets.forEach(function(e, i) {
              var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(i);

              if (i !== index) {
                // handles logic when we click on visible hidden label and there is currently at least
                // one other label that is visible and at least one other label already hidden
                // (we want to keep those already hidden still hidden)
                if (anyOthersAlreadyHidden && !allOthersHidden) {
                  meta.hidden = true;
                } else {
                  // toggle visibility
                  meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null ? !meta.hidden : null;
                }
              } else {
                meta.hidden = null;
              }
            });
          }

          ci.update();
        },
    display: true,
    position: "right",
    labels: {
  filter: function(item, chart) {
          // Logic to remove a particular legend item goes here
          return !item.text.includes('Total');
        },
      fontColor: "black",
      boxWidth: 12,
      fontFamily: "Raleway-medium"
    }
  },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        formatter: (value, ctx) => {
          const total = ctx.chart.$totalizer.totals[ctx.dataIndex]
          return total.toLocaleString('fr-FR', {
             style: 'currency',
            currency: 'EUR'
          })
        },
        align: 'end',
        anchor: 'end',
        display: function(ctx) {
          return ctx.datasetIndex === ctx.chart.$totalizer.utmost
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [totalizer]
});

$('.reset').click(function(){
//chart.ctx.legend.reset();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>

<button class='reset'>Reset</button>
<canvas id="chart" width="100" height="50"></canvas>
```

not able to show the legend all chosen on button click

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you want. Are you trying to add an "unselect all" button?  or do you want the functionality the same as it is now, just dont show the strike out? or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the version with working reset button for legend.

```js
const totalizer = {
    id: 'totalizer',
    beforeUpdate: chart => {
        let totals = {}
        let utmost = 0

            chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset, datasetIndex) => {
                if (chart.isDatasetVisible(datasetIndex)) {
                    utmost = datasetIndex
                        dataset.data.forEach((value, index) => {
                            totals[index] = (totals[index] || 0) + value
                        })
                }
            })
            chart.$totalizer = {
            totals: totals,
            utmost: utmost
        }
    }
}

const chart = new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Brut', 'Net imposable', 'Net'],
    datasets: [{"data":[10,20,10],"label":"1st Presentation \/ Meeting","backgroundColor":"#7B68EE"},{"data":[109,82,22],"label":"Hold\/Uncategorized","backgroundColor":"#B0C4DE"},{"data":[4,14,1],"label":"SGL","backgroundColor":"#F4A460"},{"data":[1,0,0],"label":"PGL","backgroundColor":"#BC8F8F"},{"data":[1,8,1],"label":"QO under evaluation","backgroundColor":"#2E8B57"},{"data":[38,37,16],"label":"Follow-On Meetings","backgroundColor":"#6495ED"},{"data":[9,6,0],"label":"MGL","backgroundColor":"#FFA500"},{"data":[6,32,0],"label":"Identified Opportunities","backgroundColor":"#6B8E23"},{"data":[0,2,0],"label":"RGL","backgroundColor":"#DEB887"}],"yearly":[{"data":[2],"label":"RGL","backgroundColor":"#DEB887"},{"data":[40],"label":"1st Presentation \/ Meeting","backgroundColor":"#7B68EE"},{"data":[10],"label":"QO under evaluation","backgroundColor":"#2E8B57"},{"data":[1],"label":"PGL","backgroundColor":"#BC8F8F"},{"data":[38],"label":"Identified Opportunities","backgroundColor":"#6B8E23"},{"data":[19],"label":"SGL","backgroundColor":"#F4A460"},{"data":[213],"label":"Hold\/Uncategorized","backgroundColor":"#B0C4DE"},{"data":[15],"label":"MGL","backgroundColor":"#FFA500"},{"data":[91],"label":"Follow-On Meetings","backgroundColor":"#6495ED"}],"user":[{"data":[0,1,0,0,2,14,7,0,1,2,0,2,1,4,0,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"Identified Opportunities","backgroundColor":"#6B8E23"},{"data":[5,2,0,9,3,0,2,6,5,0,3,0,0,0,2,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"1st Presentation \/ Meeting","backgroundColor":"#7B68EE"},{"data":[149,2,39,0,11,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"Hold\/Uncategorized","backgroundColor":"#B0C4DE"},{"data":[0,2,0,2,0,0,6,4,1,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"SGL","backgroundColor":"#F4A460"},{"data":[2,1,0,0,4,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"QO under evaluation","backgroundColor":"#2E8B57"},{"data":[7,42,0,21,8,0,5,1,0,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"Follow-On Meetings","backgroundColor":"#6495ED"},{"data":[0,3,0,6,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"MGL","backgroundColor":"#FFA500"},{"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"PGL","backgroundColor":"#BC8F8F"},{"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"RGL","backgroundColor":"#DEB887"}]},"filter":{"weekly":["Week 1","Week 2","Week 3","Week 4"]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true
       
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    },
    legend: {
       onClick: function(e, legendItem) {
          var index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
          var ci = this.chart;
          var alreadyHidden = (ci.getDatasetMeta(index).hidden === null) ? false : ci.getDatasetMeta(index).hidden;       
          var anyOthersAlreadyHidden = false;
          var allOthersHidden = true;

          // figure out the current state of the labels
          ci.data.datasets.forEach(function(e, i) {
            var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(i);
            
            if (i !== index) {
              if (meta.hidden) {
                anyOthersAlreadyHidden = true;
              } else {
                allOthersHidden = false;
              }
            }
          });
          
          // if the label we clicked is already hidden 
          // then we now want to unhide (with any others already unhidden)
          if (alreadyHidden) {
            ci.getDatasetMeta(index).hidden = null;
          } else { 
            // otherwise, lets figure out how to toggle visibility based upon the current state
            ci.data.datasets.forEach(function(e, i) {
              var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(i);

              if (i !== index) {
                // handles logic when we click on visible hidden label and there is currently at least
                // one other label that is visible and at least one other label already hidden
                // (we want to keep those already hidden still hidden)
                if (anyOthersAlreadyHidden && !allOthersHidden) {
                  meta.hidden = true;
                } else {
                  // toggle visibility
                  meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null ? !meta.hidden : null;
                }
              } else {
                meta.hidden = null;
              }
            });
          }

          ci.update();
        },
    display: true,
    position: "right",
    labels: {
  filter: function(item, chart) {
          // Logic to remove a particular legend item goes here
          return !item.text.includes('Total');
        },
      fontColor: "black",
      boxWidth: 12,
      fontFamily: "Raleway-medium"
    }
  },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        formatter: (value, ctx) => {
          const total = ctx.chart.$totalizer.totals[ctx.dataIndex]
          return total.toLocaleString('fr-FR', {
             style: 'currency',
            currency: 'EUR'
          })
        },
        align: 'end',
        anchor: 'end',
        display: function(ctx) {
          return ctx.datasetIndex === ctx.chart.$totalizer.utmost
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [totalizer]
});

$('.reset').click(function(){
  chart.data.datasets.forEach((e, i) => {
    chart.getDatasetMeta(i).hidden = null;
  });
  chart.update();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>

<button class='reset'>Reset</button>
<canvas id="chart" width="100" height="50"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

I like @Taha's solution! You can even shorten it to

```
$('.reset').click(function(){
  chart.data.datasets.forEach(e=>e._meta[0].hidden = null);
  chart.update();
});
```

```js
const totalizer = {
    id: 'totalizer',
    beforeUpdate: chart => {
        let totals = {}
        let utmost = 0

            chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset, datasetIndex) => {
                if (chart.isDatasetVisible(datasetIndex)) {
                    utmost = datasetIndex
                        dataset.data.forEach((value, index) => {
                            totals[index] = (totals[index] || 0) + value
                        })
                }
            })
            chart.$totalizer = {
            totals: totals,
            utmost: utmost
        }
    }
}

const chart = new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Brut', 'Net imposable', 'Net'],
    datasets: [{"data":[10,20,10],"label":"1st Presentation \/ Meeting","backgroundColor":"#7B68EE"},{"data":[109,82,22],"label":"Hold\/Uncategorized","backgroundColor":"#B0C4DE"},{"data":[4,14,1],"label":"SGL","backgroundColor":"#F4A460"},{"data":[1,0,0],"label":"PGL","backgroundColor":"#BC8F8F"},{"data":[1,8,1],"label":"QO under evaluation","backgroundColor":"#2E8B57"},{"data":[38,37,16],"label":"Follow-On Meetings","backgroundColor":"#6495ED"},{"data":[9,6,0],"label":"MGL","backgroundColor":"#FFA500"},{"data":[6,32,0],"label":"Identified Opportunities","backgroundColor":"#6B8E23"},{"data":[0,2,0],"label":"RGL","backgroundColor":"#DEB887"}],"yearly":[{"data":[2],"label":"RGL","backgroundColor":"#DEB887"},{"data":[40],"label":"1st Presentation \/ Meeting","backgroundColor":"#7B68EE"},{"data":[10],"label":"QO under evaluation","backgroundColor":"#2E8B57"},{"data":[1],"label":"PGL","backgroundColor":"#BC8F8F"},{"data":[38],"label":"Identified Opportunities","backgroundColor":"#6B8E23"},{"data":[19],"label":"SGL","backgroundColor":"#F4A460"},{"data":[213],"label":"Hold\/Uncategorized","backgroundColor":"#B0C4DE"},{"data":[15],"label":"MGL","backgroundColor":"#FFA500"},{"data":[91],"label":"Follow-On Meetings","backgroundColor":"#6495ED"}],"user":[{"data":[0,1,0,0,2,14,7,0,1,2,0,2,1,4,0,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"Identified Opportunities","backgroundColor":"#6B8E23"},{"data":[5,2,0,9,3,0,2,6,5,0,3,0,0,0,2,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"1st Presentation \/ Meeting","backgroundColor":"#7B68EE"},{"data":[149,2,39,0,11,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"Hold\/Uncategorized","backgroundColor":"#B0C4DE"},{"data":[0,2,0,2,0,0,6,4,1,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"SGL","backgroundColor":"#F4A460"},{"data":[2,1,0,0,4,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"QO under evaluation","backgroundColor":"#2E8B57"},{"data":[7,42,0,21,8,0,5,1,0,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"Follow-On Meetings","backgroundColor":"#6495ED"},{"data":[0,3,0,6,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"MGL","backgroundColor":"#FFA500"},{"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"PGL","backgroundColor":"#BC8F8F"},{"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"label":"RGL","backgroundColor":"#DEB887"}]},"filter":{"weekly":["Week 1","Week 2","Week 3","Week 4"]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true
       
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    },
    legend: {
       onClick: function(e, legendItem) {
          var index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
          var ci = this.chart;
          var alreadyHidden = (ci.getDatasetMeta(index).hidden === null) ? false : ci.getDatasetMeta(index).hidden;       
          var anyOthersAlreadyHidden = false;
          var allOthersHidden = true;

          // figure out the current state of the labels
          ci.data.datasets.forEach(function(e, i) {
            var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(i);
            
            if (i !== index) {
              if (meta.hidden) {
                anyOthersAlreadyHidden = true;
              } else {
                allOthersHidden = false;
              }
            }
          });
          
          // if the label we clicked is already hidden 
          // then we now want to unhide (with any others already unhidden)
          if (alreadyHidden) {
            ci.getDatasetMeta(index).hidden = null;
          } else { 
            // otherwise, lets figure out how to toggle visibility based upon the current state
            ci.data.datasets.forEach(function(e, i) {
              var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(i);

              if (i !== index) {
                // handles logic when we click on visible hidden label and there is currently at least
                // one other label that is visible and at least one other label already hidden
                // (we want to keep those already hidden still hidden)
                if (anyOthersAlreadyHidden && !allOthersHidden) {
                  meta.hidden = true;
                } else {
                  // toggle visibility
                  meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null ? !meta.hidden : null;
                }
              } else {
                meta.hidden = null;
              }
            });
          }

          ci.update();
        },
    display: true,
    position: "right",
    labels: {
  filter: function(item, chart) {
          // Logic to remove a particular legend item goes here
          return !item.text.includes('Total');
        },
      fontColor: "black",
      boxWidth: 12,
      fontFamily: "Raleway-medium"
    }
  },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        formatter: (value, ctx) => {
          const total = ctx.chart.$totalizer.totals[ctx.dataIndex]
          return total.toLocaleString('fr-FR', {
             style: 'currency',
            currency: 'EUR'
          })
        },
        align: 'end',
        anchor: 'end',
        display: function(ctx) {
          return ctx.datasetIndex === ctx.chart.$totalizer.utmost
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [totalizer]
});

$('.reset').click(function(){
  chart.data.datasets.forEach(e=>e._meta[0].hidden = null);
  chart.update();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>

<button class='reset'>Reset</button>
<canvas id="chart" width="100" height="50"></canvas>
```

Comment: In general, it is not a good practice to access or modify fields which start with an underscore.

Comment: Yeah, I get it. I guess they are meant to be "private" and are not guaranteed to remain unchanged in future releases. Point taken! So, my contribution should be seen more like a "hack" than a "solution". ;-)